# How to do a select insert statement in sql with a changing value in the column for each row

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically what I am trying to do in sql is find a way to do a select insert statement where all of the values in the other columns will stay the same but one of the columns value will increase by 1 for every row that is created. I am wondering if there is a way to do that in SQL.

Comment: Are you looking to add 1 to one of the columns, or increment the value as the columns go.   For example: A)  add 1 to row one, then add 1 to row 2,   
or B) add 1 to row 1, and then add 2 to row 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 + 1
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

Then, after the `INSERT`, the table contains:

> | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 | 2 |
> | 3 | 3 | 3 |
> | 1 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2 | 2 | 3 |
> | 3 | 3 | 4 |

And the `col1` and `col2` values of the inserted rows are the same and the `col3` values have been incremented by 1.

If you want to increment the values by the number of rows being inserted then you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 + COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM   table_name
```

---

#### However

If you are attempting to add multiple rows and keep `col3` with unique values then you should not use that method and should use a sequence.

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL, table_name__col3__seq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

Then you can insert the rows using:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, table_name__col3__seq.NEXTVAL
FROM   table_name
```

and `col3` will be populated using the next sequence values.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=59f0924f8e53524b9feb8ca5d9ee19d8)*